# how do i prevent Flickering in Tflowpanel?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

i am adding some Timage control To Tflowpanel with the following code

```
procedure TForm1.AddToFlow(AGpath : string);
var
aGIF:TGIFImage;
aimage : Timage;
begin

aGIF := TGIFImage.Create;
try

aGIF.LoadFromFile(AGpath);

aimage := Timage.Create(FlOWPANEL);
aimage.Parent  := FlOWPANEL;
aimage.Center := True;
aimage.Picture.Graphic := aGIF;

finally
FreeAndNil(aGIF);
end;


end;
```

but each Time i add TImage The FlowPanel and the Timages inside it Start To Flickering any idea how to Avoid Flickering in this case ?

Comment: Thank God Someone asked this question in 2020!!

Answer (score 1):

In case of flickering components you can set the property `DoubleBuffered := True`. This will redraw the component before actually refreshing it on the screen.

Comment: the flowpanel is inside a scrollbox, doublebuffered wont help in this case

Comment: You will need to set the `DoubleBuffered`property to all components. In your case the TFlowPanel, the TScrollBox and eventually the TImage as well.